# How to deploy ssrs on local?

Tags: reporting-services

How do I deploy ssrs on my local machine?

I am using ssrs 2005.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure bout 2005 but in 2008, you right click on project -> properties and change the following:

TargetDatasetFolder: /FolderName/DataSet
TargetDataSourceFolder:  /FolderName/DataSource
TargetReportFolder:     /FolderName
TargetReportPartFolder:    /FolderName
TargetServerURL:

```
http://localhost/MainFolderName (u can ommit the MainFolderName if you dont want it)
```

Then you can right click on the project and click deploy and VOILA

Thank you,
KrizD

Answer (score 1):

Primarily on the local machine must have installed MS Report Server 2005

When you publish. RDL file in the folder, you need to set the path to the address where the report server